# Electric Field of a uniformly charged sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

I'm calculating the eletric field of a uniformly charged sphere so that I can compare it with the potential of a uniformly polarized sphere.

So I calculated using the eletric displacement, $\overrightarrow{D}$. I did not use Gauss's Law because I only know the free charge of the sphere, $Q_{fenc}$, and Gauss's law requires the total charge (free and poralized). So, by using the electric displacement, I solved this issue, because it only requires the free charge.

So, I used: $$\int_{S}\overrightarrow{D}\cdot d\overrightarrow{a}=Q_{fenc}$$ and I got the right result.
For $r>R$:
$$\overrightarrow{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{Q}{r^{2}}\hat{r}$$

For $r<R$:
$$\overrightarrow{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\frac{Q}{r^{2}}r\hat{r}$$

My question is, I saw somewhere that we can get this field using this formula:
$$d\overrightarrow{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{dq}{r^{2}}\hat{r}$$
and it says that this formula follows from the Coulomb's Law. But how do I get this formula?

I know that the Coulomb formula gives:
$$F=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{q_{1}q_{2}}{r^{2}}$$

And by the Lorentz force I can get $\overrightarrow{E}$:
$$F=q(\overrightarrow{E}+\overrightarrow{v}\times\overrightarrow{B})$$

But what about the magnetic field? Don't we consider it?

Comment: If the charges are stationary the magnetic contribution in Lorentz formula disappears since the velocity is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of this exercise, there's no magnetic field so $\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$ with $q$ the charge on which the force is applied.

If $Q$ is a point-like charge that generates the force and the field:
$$\vec{F}=\frac{Qq}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r^2}\,\hat{r}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\vec{E}=\frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r^2}\,\hat{r}$$

Now if the source isn't point-like, split it into small pieces, each containing a charge $dQ$. Each of these small pieces is considered point-like, so each generates an electric field:
$$d\vec{E}=\frac{dQ}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r^2}\,\hat{r}$$
with $r$ being the distance to this small piece.

The usual continuation is to see what sort of charge distribution the source is, and to write $dQ$ accordingly (for instance $dQ=\rho\,dV$ for a volumetric source). Then you can sum over all the small pieces to get the total field.

For problems with enough symmetries, Gauss law is far easier to use than this.